# A simple select statement is taking too much of time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, rdbms

The following simple select statement is is taking too much of time to execute:

```
select * from sys_letter_intid
```

sys_letter_intid table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sys_letter_intid](
[intid] [int] NULL,
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[misc_text] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[misc_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[misc_amount] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Not sure about the number of rows because even SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys_letter_intid and select top 1 * from sys_letter_intid order by intid desc query is taking too much time to execute.

- Index Space - 0.023 MB
- Row Count - 1
- Data Space - 0.008 MB

sp_lock gives the following output:

```
spid   dbid   ObjId       IndId  Type Resource                         Mode     Status
------ ------ ----------- ------ ---- -------------------------------- -------- ------
52     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
54     8      1185439297  0      TAB                                   IX       GRANT
54     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
55     5      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
56     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
56     8      2049442375  1      KEY  (716bd5e0da25)                   X        GRANT
56     8      2049442375  0      TAB                                   IX       GRANT
56     8      2049442375  1      PAG  1:29168                          IX       GRANT
58     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
60     1      2107154552  0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
60     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
61     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
61     8      2049442375  1      PAG  1:29168                          IS       GRANT
61     8      2049442375  1      KEY  (716bd5e0da25)                   S        WAIT
61     8      2049442375  0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
62     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
63     5      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
64     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
66     8      0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
```

SP_Who2 gives the following output:

```
SPID  Status                         Login                                                                          HostName        BlkBy DBName                       Command          CPUTime DiskIO LastBatch      ProgramName                                                        SPID  REQUESTID
----- ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ --------------- ----- ---------------------------- ---------------- ------- ------ -------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ ----- ---------
1     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         LOG WRITER       234     0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    1     0    
2     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         LAZY WRITER      608     0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    2     0    
3     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         RECOVERY WRITER  93      0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    3     0    
4     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         LOCK MONITOR     0       0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    4     0    
5     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       SIGNAL HANDLER   0       0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    5     0    
6     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         XE DISPATCHER    62      0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    6     0    
7     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         RESOURCE MONITOR 780     0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    7     0    
8     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         XE TIMER         0       0      02/27 03:22:02                                                                    8     0    
9     BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       BRKR TASK        0       0      02/27 03:22:40                                                                    9     0    
10    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      02/27 03:22:03                                                                    10    0    
11    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TRACE QUEUE TASK 0       0      02/27 03:22:03                                                                    11    0    
12    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         SYSTEM_HEALTH_MO 0       0      02/27 03:22:04                                                                    12    0    
13    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         RECEIVE          312     2      02/27 03:22:04                                                                    13    0    
14    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       159    03/12 22:46:23                                                                    14    0    
15    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       1      03/12 22:46:23                                                                    15    0    
16    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       CHECKPOINT       109     159    02/27 03:22:34                                                                    16    0    
17    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      02/27 03:22:34                                                                    17    0    
18    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   NULL                         UNKNOWN TOKEN    0       0      02/27 03:23:35                                                                    18    0    
19    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       4      03/12 22:36:22                                                                    19    0    
20    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      03/12 22:46:33                                                                    20    0    
21    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      03/12 22:33:17                                                                    21    0    
22    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      03/12 22:46:33                                                                    22    0    
23    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      03/12 22:50:39                                                                    23    0    
24    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      03/12 22:43:18                                                                    24    0    
25    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       BRKR EVENT HNDLR 0       41     02/27 03:22:40                                                                    25    0    
26    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       BRKR TASK        218     0      02/27 03:22:40                                                                    26    0    
27    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       BRKR TASK        31      0      02/27 03:22:40                                                                    27    0    
28    BACKGROUND                     sa                                                                               .               .   master                       BRKR TASK        0       0      02/27 03:22:40                                                                    28    0    
29    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       7      03/12 22:50:39                                                                    29    0    
30    sleeping                       sa                                                                               .               .   master                       TASK MANAGER     0       0      03/12 22:50:39                                                                    30    0    
51    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   master                       AWAITING COMMAND 157     283    03/13 01:15:51 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                             51    0    
52    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 16      1      03/13 01:33:08 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                     52    0    
53    sleeping                       NT SERVICE\ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER2012                                        WIN-07VQ7EIB4L1   .   ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER2012 AWAITING COMMAND 0       0      03/13 01:40:09 Report Server                                                      53    0    
54    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 218     0      03/13 01:28:50 jTDS                                                               54    0    
55    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 0       0      03/13 01:29:34 jTDS                                                               55    0    
56    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 376     5      03/13 01:31:11 jTDS                                                               56    0    
57    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   master                       AWAITING COMMAND 16      38     03/13 01:40:22 Database Engine Tuning Advisor                                     57    0    
58    sleeping                       NT SERVICE\ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER2012                                        WIN-07VQ7EIB4L1   .   ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER2012 AWAITING COMMAND 0       0      03/13 01:41:14 Report Server                                                      58    0    
59    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   master                       AWAITING COMMAND 0       0      03/13 00:50:47 Database Engine Tuning Advisor                                     59    0    
60    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 125     7      03/13 01:17:27 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                     60    0    
62    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 202     0      03/13 01:41:20 jTDS                                                               62    0    
63    sleeping                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 718     8      03/13 01:29:35 jTDS                                                               63    0    
64    SUSPENDED                      admin                                                                          CGVAK-328       55    PUC                          DELETE           0       0      03/13 01:31:11 jTDS                                                               64    0    
65    sleeping                       admin                                                                          DEVARAJ-PC        .   master                       AWAITING COMMAND 374     0      03/13 01:15:05 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                             65    0    
66    sleeping                       admin                                                                          DEVARAJ-PC        .   PUC                          AWAITING COMMAND 0       0      03/13 01:31:50 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                     66    0    
67    sleeping                       admin                                                                          DEVARAJ-PC        .   master                       AWAITING COMMAND 0       0      03/13 01:31:46 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Transact-SQL IntelliSense 67    0    
68    sleeping                       admin                                                                          DEVARAJ-PC        .   master                       AWAITING COMMAND 0       0      03/13 01:33:19 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Transact-SQL IntelliSense 68    0    
69    RUNNABLE                       admin                                                                          CGVAK-328         .   PUC                          SELECT INTO      31      8      03/13 01:33:29 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query                     69    0    

(48 row(s) affected)
```

Following is the output for SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where blocking_session_id <>0

```
session_id request_id  start_time              status                         command                          sql_handle                                                                                                                         statement_start_offset statement_end_offset plan_handle                                                                                                                        database_id user_id     connection_id                        blocking_session_id wait_type                                                    wait_time   last_wait_type                                               wait_resource                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    open_transaction_count open_resultset_count transaction_id       context_info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       percent_complete estimated_completion_time cpu_time    total_elapsed_time scheduler_id task_address       reads                writes               logical_reads        text_size   language                                                                                                                         date_format date_first quoted_identifier arithabort ansi_null_dflt_on ansi_defaults ansi_warnings ansi_padding ansi_nulls concat_null_yields_null transaction_isolation_level lock_timeout deadlock_priority row_count            prev_error  nest_level  granted_query_memory executing_managed_code group_id    query_hash         query_plan_hash
---------- ----------- ----------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------- ------------------------- ----------- ------------------ ------------ ------------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------------- ---------- ----------------- ------------- ------------- ------------ ---------- ----------------------- --------------------------- ------------ ----------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- ---------------------- ----------- ------------------ ------------------
64         0           2014-03-13 01:31:11.927 suspended                      DELETE                           0x0200000095E2BC33A9AC347266EB7BD07B54F63FA636143300000000000000000000000000000000                                                 0                      -1                   0x0600080095E2BC3330BCFB1501000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                 8           1           07E2265C-3159-4099-B6DF-8B2A8FCA4BB9 55                  LCK_M_U                                                      137240      LCK_M_U                                                      KEY: 8:72057596467675136 (915ffb6f1e99)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          2                      1                    6920013              0x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0                0                         0           137240             1            0x638702F8         0                    0                    2                    2147483647  us_english                                                                                                                       mdy         7          1                 0          1                 0             1             1            1          1                       2                           -1           0                 0                    0           1           0                    0                      1           0x83FE4907FA5F0EF2 0x873EF4A76D497C0C

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 and following is the execution plan.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.3128.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0032831" StatementText="select * from sys_letter_intid" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x806EE30ADB72F191" QueryPlanHash="0x47B522D12A52B90C" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="8" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="56">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="104702" EstimatedPagesCached="9938" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="85" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="1">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="intid" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="id" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="misc_text" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="misc_Date" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="misc_amount" />
              </OutputList>
              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="intid" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="id" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="misc_text" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="misc_Date" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Column="misc_amount" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[PUC]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sys_letter_intid]" Index="[IDX_sys_letter_intid]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: How many **rows** and what kind of **columns** does this table have? And do you **really** need **ALL** columns (`SELECT *`) and **ALL** rows (no `WHERE` clause) from your table? If you really need **everything** from that table - there's really no "magic" way to speed up the clustered index scan .....

Comment: Yes @marc_s I need all the columns

Comment: Right click the table in SSMS and click Properties, then Storage.  You should see a row count listed.

Comment: If you want the number of rows, just use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys_letter_intid table`.  Your `TOP 1` query is using `Order by`, so this will be slow, especially if there's a lot of rows, and no `index`.

Comment: @JiggsJedi I have updated row count.

Comment: Is there a lock on that table?

Comment: If the query never completes, you must be getting the estimated execution plan, and not the actual.  Since it has one row, you either have the slowest computer on earth or @MichaelTodd is correct.  Try: *select * from sys_letter_intid WITH (NOLOCK)*

Comment: You should avoid naming tables that start with `sys`. But other than that your server is ether pegged so it can't even process simple sql or something has a lock on a table that is not being released.

Comment: Thanks @PhilSandler WITH(NOLOCK) works.

Comment: Important: How long did it take to produce this query plan?

Comment: What is proc 56 doing?  Whatever it is is probably blocking this query from running.

Comment: Does this `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where blocking_session_id <>0` return anything?

Comment: I'd run an SP_Who2 and see if any of the SPIDs are blocking your process.

Comment: So you are SPID 64, being blocked by SPID 55.  You need to track down CGVAK-328 and tell them to close their connection to SPID 55 because you need access to your table and it's blocking you.

Comment: FYI - You don't need the WITH keyword when using (NOLOCK). `select * from table (nolock)` works.

Comment: @John Omitting the WITH keyword is a deprecated feature: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Comment: If you have a ton of tables in the execution batch, you can instead type `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` at the top of the query batch and the effect is essentially the same as placing `(nolock)` hints on every table you're selecting from.

Comment: Did you define the primary key for the table, in this case I would think [id] should be the primary key.

Answer (score 3):

To close out this question, with credit to the comments by Michael Todd, RBarryYoung, and Phil Sandler, the SELECT was taking a long time because it was being blocked by a another process. Using `WITH (NOLOCK)` on the `SELECT` statement bypassed the update lock (LCK_M_U), allowing the statement to proceed.

See also HOT theChunKk's comment noting that using a different isolation level for the transaction (e.g. `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted`) is an alternative to using `NOLOCK` on the `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Might Have Used **Begin Tran**, Which Cause Even Simple Query To Execute Late If the Enclosing Command like **RollBack** Or **Commit** is not Used After Using the **Begin tran** Command.

Comment: This was my exact problem! I don't get why it's been downvoted ? Anyway, thanks! :D